# What people are considered to be part of "populus"?

Tags: vocabulary

Lewis and Short give the following in the [dictionary entry for *populus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpopulus1):

> 1. *The people*, opp. to the Senate, in the formula senatus populusque Romanus (abbreviated S. P. Q. R.), saep.; cf.: “et patres in populi fore potestate,” Liv. 2, 56.—
> 2. Opp. to the plebs: “non enim populi, sed plebis eum (tribunum) magistratum esse,” Liv. 2, 56: “ut ea res populo plebique Romanae bene eveniret,” Cic. Mur. 1, 1.—
> 3. Rarely for plebs, *the populace*: “dat populus, dat gratus eques, dat tura senatus,” Mart. 8, 15, 3: urbanus, *the citizens* (opp. to the military), Nep. Cim. 2, 1.—

In the classical era, what groups of people were understood to be included in the term *populus*? How does it relate to *civis* and *plebs*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantic range of ***populus*** is closest to that of "nation" meaning "a stable **community of people** formed on the basis of shared culture, language, history, ethnicity etc.", but not connected to the concept of a nation-state and so closer to "people", "population". The term cuts across political and class distinctions, and when used as "population" all the native inhabitants of a given territory are included. Slaves are an obvious question mark, being originally the clear outsiders and few in number, but with the stratospheric rise of chattel slavery and the porous border between slavery and freedom there was no longer a definite answer to this question.

The pairing *populus <> **senātus*** doesn't imply exclusion like "the nation and its leaders" doesn't exclude the leaders from the nation, but specifies the latter as a political class inside the former.

Likewise *nōn populī sed **plēbis** magistrātus* means that he represents the interests of only the **lowest order** of the populace, and ordinarily of just one city - Rome, i.e. *plēps urbāna.* Just like there may have been any number of councils in other cities, it's almost always the Roman one that is meant by *senātus* since political power was concentrated in the capital which had by far the largest population, and the power of the plebeians was in their numbers.

The concept of ***cīvis*** is a political privilege, a **legal status vis-à-vis the (city-)state.** It was granted to all free-born natives of Rome, but could be (and famously was) extended to others by decree - it was a franchise. Like the previous two terms it could be used to mean *cīvis Rōmānus;* it was also used of non-Roman citizenship, but mainly with Greek city-states as you had to be a Roman citizen to have any political power in a Roman province. It doesn't seem like Caracalla's universal extension of Roman citizenship resulted in any further conflation either, since the decline of the democratic process made the status symbolic. When power shifted to the provinces as the empire was fragmenting, *cīvis* together with *cīvitās* became terms for **local political entities,** which in medieval Italy shrank to small towns (*città*), Roman *oppida*.

The comparison wouldn't be complete without mentioning ***vulgus*** "the common folk, the multitude, the collective everyman." Unlike *populus* or *cīvēs* this isn't a conscious group identity, but simply the **mass of people** whose special characteristic is having no special characteristic, and as such it can be used unflatteringly.

Ergō cum dīcimus ***Rōmānōs*** aut *populum Rōmānum* dīcimus aut *cīvīs Rōmānōs*, sed *vulgus* vix et *plēbem* numquam.